# How to use defined variables in __init__ method all over the code?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-menu

Here, I am trying to build a text editor using python and tkinter and OOP. But the problem is I am unable to use predefined variables in the code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk, Menu, Label, PhotoImage, StringVar, IntVar
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

PROGRAM_NAME = 'PyEdit'


class TextEditor:

    def __init__(self, root):

        self.root = root
        self.root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self.root._w, photo)
        self.root.title(PROGRAM_NAME)
        self.root.geometry('350x280')
        self.init_gui()

        self.title_image = Image.open('Text-Edit-icon.png')
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(title_image)
        self.help = Image.open('icons/helpicon.png')
        self.new_icon = PhotoImage(file='icons/new_file.gif')
        self.save_icon = PhotoImage(file='icons/save.gif')
        self.cut_icon = PhotoImage(file='icons/cut.gif')
        self.copy_icon = PhotoImage(file='icons/copy.gif')
        self.undo_icon = PhotoImage(file='icons/undo.gif')
        self.open_icon = PhotoImage(file='icons/open_file.gif')
        self.about_icon = PhotoImage(file='icons/about.gif')
        self.redo_icon = PhotoImage(file='icons/redo.gif')
        self.find_icon = PhotoImage(file='icons/onfind.gif')
        self.help_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(help)
        self.paste_icon = PhotoImage(file='icons/paste.gif')

    def create_menu_bar(self):
        menu_bar = Menu(self.root)
        edit_menu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
        edit_menu.add_command(label='Undo', accelerator='Ctrl-Z', image=self.undo_icon)
        edit_menu.add_command(label='Redo', accelerator='Ctrl-Y', image=self.redo_icon)
        edit_menu.add_command(label='Cut', accelerator='Ctrl-X', image=self.cut_icon)
        edit_menu.add_command(label='Copy', accelerator='Ctrl-C', image=self.copy_icon)
        edit_menu.add_command(label='Paste', accelerator='Ctrl-V', image=self.paste_icon)
        edit_menu.add_separator()
        edit_menu.add_command(label='Select All', accelerator='Ctrl-A', )
        menu_bar.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu=edit_menu)
        self.root.config(menu=menu_bar)

    def init_gui(self):
        self.create_menu_bar()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    TextEditor(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

The error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SoundBoard.py", line 51, in <module>
     TextEditor(root)
  File "SoundBoard.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.init_gui()
  File "SoundBoard.py", line 47, in init_gui
    self.create_menu_bar()
  File "SoundBoard.py", line 36, in create_menu_bar
    edit_menu.add_command(label='Undo', accelerator='Ctrl-Z', image=self.undo_icon)
AttributeError: 'TextEditor' object has no attribute 'undo_icon'
```

I tried placing the photoimage block on other location it doesn't work. I also tried it in `create_menu_bar` then there is no error but it also doesn't work.

Comment: You need to make sure the attributes are defined before trying to reference them.

Answer (score 5):

I think its simply because you've put `self.init_gui()` before initializing your variables, put it at the end of the `__init__` method and it should work I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but another error occurred .
`AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'`

Comment: @S.Kalyankar That is a new problem best asked in a new question. abcdaire's answer is correct for the original issue in your question. I suspect your error might be due to `photo` as it is not defined anywhere in your code.  Also you have this line `self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(title_image)` and it should be `self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.title_image)` instead. That also leads me to believe that `photo` should be `self.photo` and `tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self.root._w, photo)` should come after where you load the image to `self.photo`.